# How can I download data from a server in cocoa (not touch)?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, download

Like it's written in the title, How can I download data from a server in my Cocoa Application?
So far I looked for, I found [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#downloading_the_response_directly_to_a_file) works for iPhone and Mac

Answer (score 3):

If you're not downloading a lot of things in parallel and you're doing a simple GET request, the easiest way to do it is to dispatch a synchronous request to one of the global queues:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
  NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"]];
  NSURLResponse* response = nil;
  NSError* error = nil;
  NSData* result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
  // There will be response data in response now, like the http status code
  // etc. You should check this information to make sure you didn't get a 404
  // or some other http status error
  if( result ) {
    // you have a good result, do something with it like create a new object or
    // pass it to a method on this object, etc.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      [self doSomethingWithResponseData:result];
    });
  } else {
    // You got an error making the connection, so handle it
    NSLog(@"Error making connection: %@", error);
  }
});
```

**note: this sample code uses GCD and therefore will only run on Snow Leopard (10.6) or better. If you need to target Leopard or Tiger, you can do the same thing using dispatched thread selectors, but not as in-line.